# Regular Expression for specific requirements

Tags: c#, .net, regex, pattern-matching

Following is my collection of strings, which refer to path from begin to end, each element like `ABC` is a city terminal:

```
"ABC-DEF-MNO-JKL-LOO"
"BYT-JKU-PLO-MNO"
"DEF-BYT-IOT-POC-LOO"
"LMN-RTX-PQS-JYY"
"LMN-PQS-IRJ"
```

I have developed the following Regex patterns to take care of business requirement:

Requirement1 - `Start with ABC or DEF, pass via MNO or BYT, End with LOO,JYY,IRJ`

```
Pattern 1 - `@"(^ABC|^DEF).*(MNO|BYT).*(LOO$|JYY$|IRJ$)";`
Result 1 - "ABC-DEF-MNO-JKL-LOO", "DEF-BYT-IOT-POC-LOO"
```

Requirement2 - `Start with ABC or DEF, pass via MNO or BYT, exclude route with IOT and End with LOO,JYY,IRJ`

```
 Expected Result - "ABC-DEF-MNO-JKL-LOO", since the other route has IOT

Expected Pattern - `@"(^ABC|^DEF).*(MNO|BYT).*^(IOT).*(LOO$|JYY$|IRJ$)";`
```

but this one fails to provide any result

```
Successful Pattern - `@"(^ABC|^DEF).*(MNO|BYT.*^(IOT)).*(LOO$|JYY$|IRJ$)";`
```

However I am not convinced, this is the correct way to achieve it, can anyone help in understanding:

- Why Expected Pattern doesn't helps in yielding correct result, I cannot understand what's wrong in it
- Suggest a better Regular expression to achieve the same result

**Edit 1:**

Based on the response provided by the @Sebastian, following pattern also succeed:

`@"^(?:ABC|DEF).*(?:MNO|BYT)(?!.*IOT).*(?:LOO|JYY|IRJ)$"`

but following pattern fails, when there's just extra `.*`

`@"^(?:ABC|DEF).*(?:MNO|BYT).*(?!.*IOT).*(?:LOO|JYY|IRJ)$"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `^(?:ABC|DEF)(?!.*IOT).*(?:MNO|BYT).*(?:LOO|JYY|IRJ)$` to meet your second requirement. This uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid matching, if `IOT` is present. The rest is taken from your pattern, just making the groups non capturing and moving the anchors outside the groups.

Your pseudo successful pattern uses the following `(MNO|BYT.*^(IOT))` which matches either `MNO` or `BYT.*^(IOT)`, so there is no check for `IOT` if `MNO` is present in your string. Also `^(IOT)` matches start of the string + `IOT`, which will never be present inside the string.

Comment: This leads to correct answer, but I fail to understand, why would you put `^(?!.*IOT)` at the beginning, why not as per logic somewhere inside

Comment: Please check the Edit based on your response, does it means the position of `^(?!.*IOT)` is irrelevant, it can be anywhere

Comment: @MrinalKamboj you should do some research on lookarounds, `(?!.*IOT)` is a negative lookahead, thus an assertion that what's inside cannot be matched. Thus it should be present as early as possible and needed. Note that your first pattern in the edit will match `ABC-MNO-IOT-BYT-IRJ`.

Comment: Sure thanks, so as per you we should ideally put that in the beginning to do the assertion

Comment: @MrinalKamboj this heavily depends on actual requirements. If a certain substring should not be present anywhere (as in your case), then yes.

Comment: @SebastianProske yes my requirement would be strict, that it shouldn't be anywhere

Comment: @maraca If efficiency is an issue, one could make the `.*` more explicit, something like `^(?:ABC|DEF)(?!-(?:\w{3}-)*IOT)-(?:\w{3}-)*?(?:MNO|BYT)-(?:\w{3}-)*?(?:LOO|JYY|IRJ)$` is a bit more efficient (and way less readable).

Comment: Not if you segment it like me with the minus... anyway I already upvoted, but I tend to be as strict as possible in my regex. E.g. I will only match flight lines and nothing else... almost.

Answer (score 1):

Starts with ABC or DEF: `^(?:ABC|DEF)-`

pass via MNO or BYT: `(?:MNO|BYT)-`

exclude route with IOT: `(?!IOT)-`

and end with LOO,JYY,IRJ: `(?:LOO|JYY|IRJ)$`

Put it all together:

```
^(?:ABC|DEF)-(?:(?!IOT)[A-Z]{3}-)*?(?:MNO|BYT)-(?:(?!IOT)[A-Z]{3}-)*(?:LOO|JYY|IRJ)$
```

Comment: Thanks its quite logical to understand, I have tried the modified usage to add more flexibility for my use case:

`^(?:ABC|DEF)(?!.*IOT).*(?:MNO|BYT)(?!.*IOT).*(?:LOO|JYY|IRJ)$`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj see Sebastian's answer if flexibility is the goal, if you are using `.*` in the lookahead then it's sufficient to have it once. if you want to allow more letters, let's say 2-4, then you do this in the repetitions `{2,4}`

Comment: When you put in {3,4} then RIOT would be a valid airport... but IOTA wouldn't be, so the regex would have to be adjusted if IOTA should be a valid airport and only IOT should be blocked, same goes for the flexible version.

Comment: In the version above you can do the lookahead for `IOT-` to correct this, in the flexible version `.*-IOT-`.